# What is a statment prefix in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
let b = 10
x: a = b
b // 10
a // 10
x // Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

What is `x` and how `a` exists without declaring it first?

Comment: [Labelled statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Comment: `a` *does* exist, you assigned to it with `a=b`

Comment: `a` is implicit global.

Comment: As it stands how OP shows it, it is invalid syntax.

Comment: it's not invalid syntax in chrome. maybe in other browsers, it is.

Comment: @connexo no it is not invalid; try it. Any statement can be labelled.

Comment: @Pointy Run it in latest Firefox. `"message": "ReferenceError: x is not defined",`

Comment: @connexo sure, that's an error because in fact `x` is not defined as a variable of any kind. The label part, which I think was the point of the question, is fine however. (Pointless, but syntactically correct.)